# HTML5 Regex Pattern for textbox validation: allow alphabet, spaces, and certain characters only

Tags: regex, html, validation

I am creating a form in html and for a text input, I want to have a regex validation on it that only allows the user to input: letters of the alphabet, numbers and certain characters;

```
/ - forward slash

- - hyphen

. - period (full stop)

& - ampersand

  - spaces
```

I have tried this pattern but to no avail:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\.\&\ ]
```

My HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="payment_reference" name="payment_reference" maxlength="18" value="' . $payment_reference_default . '" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\.\&\ ]" required>
```

I know how to get only alphabet characters and numbers, but allowing the other characters as well is something I'm unable to manage.

Comment: It should work. What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2023 Update**

Now, you need to always escape the literal hyphen inside character classes at the end of the character class, so use

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9/.& \-]+"
```

**Originial answer**

You need to remove escaping from **every non-special char** because in FF (and Chrome) the HTML5 regex is compiled with `u` modifier, and it lays bigger restriction on the pattern. To enable matching 1 or more allowed chars, add `+` after the character class:

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9/.& -]+"
```

Note that all special chars in your pattern except `-` are not special inside a character class. Hence, only `-` can be escaped, but it is common to put it at the start/end of the character class to avoid overescaping.

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9/.& -]+" title="Please enter the data in correct format." />
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape character properly.

`-` i am not escaping it here because when you use it as first or last character in character class you don't need to escape

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\/.&\s-]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D68Rzk/2/)

Comment: I tried your syntax with the following string '2WestStreetL341LQ' and I get 'Invalid format.' returned by Firefox

Comment: Strange, it works on your regex checker but not in Firefox Quantum 64.0 (64-bit)